# I simple search controller that stores search history, should I use resource routing or non-resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am learning rails and am toying with a simple web-app that integrates with flickr to search photos based on user given criteria and store the query in a search history table.

I am seeking the best or 'rails' way of handling this. Should I setup a controller and non-resource routes that handle the search and store the data in a custom table; or should I create a resource for queries with a resource route and an additional path for search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My thoughts:

In config/routes.rb:

```
match '/search/:query' => 'search#search', :as => 'search'
```

Create a `SearchController`:

```
rails generate controller search
```

In app/controllers/search_controller.rb:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
    # Use params[:query] to perform the search
  end
end
```

For example, a query for "apples" would appear as: http://example.com/search/apples

You can generate links to queries with: `search_path('apples')`

Answer (score 7):

Lemme refactor a bit:

```
rails g controller searches
```

This neat rule will allow you to use nifty action-per-resource searches controller:

```
# config/routes.rb
get 'search/:action' => 'searches#:action'
```

Here's simplified version of such one:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

  def foos
    search do
      Foo.where :name => params[:q]
    end
  end

  def bars
    search do
      Bar.where :title => params[:q]
    end
  end

  private

  def search(&block)    
    if params[:q]
      @results = yield if block_given?

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # resources.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @results }
      end
    else
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'No search query was specified.'
    end
  end

end
```

Examples of URL queries:

```
/search/foos?q=baz
/search/bars?q=baz
```